# PHP Script that inserts URL variables into a mysql db?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm looking for a simple and secure script to insert rows into a mysql table from a php script.

by calling http://www.myserver.com/addtosometable.php?1=asdf&2=asdf....

I'm not asking how specifically, rather I thought this might be a good platform to build a example script and keep it up to date with best practices...

Cheers

Comment: I thought we might develop an example script that includes the variable cleaning etc...

Answer (score 2):

all the URL variables (GET variables) are put into the PHP variable `$_GET` as an array.

Using your example above `myfile.php?1=asdf&2=asdf` your script would have access to an array that looks like this:

```
array(
    1 => "asdf"
    2 => "asdf"
)
```

If you want to see this for yourself, just put this in your file:

```
print_r($_GET);
```

From there it should be a simple task of **cleaning the variables to avoid injection attacks** and then creating an INSERT statement. I'd need to know more about your table structure and whatnot to help you specifically with that. See the docs on [mysql_real_escape_string](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

Comment: It might also help to take a look at the urlencode/decode functions, if the content you want to pass contains special chars, like >,<, space, etc..

See: http://br2.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Comment: i believe that the variables will already be decoded when they're in $_GET

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MySQL 5, you can use prepared statements to avoid most forms of SQL Injection.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO table ( col1, col2 ) values ( ?, ? );
// check for errors 
$result = $stmt->execute( $_GET['1'], $_GET['2'] );
// check for errors
```

I believe you still have to worry about XSS (Cross-Site-Scripting) attacks, but that's beyond my ken.

Comment: The example provided is using MDB2, which is indeed a DB framework.  You can use mysqli->prepare() just as well, but it involves more statements (prepare, bind_param, execute, bind_result, fetch), compared to 3 with MDB2 (prepare, execute, fetch)

Comment: MDB2 is pretty painless to implement, and you can install PEAR modules without being root or even having shell access, so there's no excuse to not use a DB framework.